# C++ operator+ overload singly linkedlist

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to write an operator overload for a linked list which will take the right hand side of the + and concatenate that linked list to the list on the left hand side.

Class declaration:

```
 List<T>& operator+(const List<T>& right);
```

Method:

```
template <typename T>
List<T>& List<T>::operator+(const List<T>& right){
    List result(*this);
    while(right->next != NULL){
         result->push_back(right->data);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Driver:

```
mylist + mylist2; //both list objects already created.
```

Error message:

```
 Error: The operation "List<std::string>* + List<std::string>*" is illegal.
```

I'm unsure of why I get the compile time error.  My logic is to take each element of the list on the right hand side and simply push it to the back of the list on the left hand side. Thoughts?

Comment: If you want to concatenate to an existing list, it would make more sense to overload `+=`. The `+` operator should return a new list. But you have two big errors: you return a reference to a local variable, and you seem to be attempting to add two pointers.

Comment: Judging by the error message, `mylist1` and `mylist2` aren't `List`s, they're pointers. And you can't add pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact error you are reporting is probably in code you have not shown, but it is important to point out that `operator+` should not return a reference. You need a member operator

```
List<T> operator+(const List<T>& right);
```

or a non-member version,

```
template <typename T>
List<T> operator+(const List<T>& lhs, const List<T>& rhs);
```

You can implement either in terms of a member `+=` operator, where you append the elements of `lhs` to `*this` and return `*this` by reference. The logic in your example is flawed, I leave it up to you to fix that, but this is the general form:

```
List<T>& operator+=(const List<T>& rhs)
{
  // append elements from rhs into *this
  ....
  return *this;
}
```

Your `operator+` implementation then becomes quite simple:

```
template <typename T>
List<T> operator+(const List<T>& lhs, const List<T>& rhs)
{
  List<T> tmp = lhs;
  tmp += rhs;
  return tmp;
}
```

Comment: So Im to understand that I need to overload both the operator+ and operator+= in order to correctly concatenate the two lists?

Comment: @user1822789 you don't *have* to implement `operator+` using `operator+=`, but usually it makes sense to do it this way.